# resizing uitableview won't respond to uibutton controls inside uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` with height 500. On the scroll, I programmatically increase its size to 600 by setting its frame, and it works fine.

But now the problem is the 100 pixel portion which I just increase won't respond to `UIButton` controls inside `UITableView`. Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: just check whether if some view is blocking it or not

Comment: what do you mean by blocking please?

Comment: Open app in simulator-->on top you see debug-->in it you will see color blended layers. Clicking on it you can see whether some other view is on top of your tableview at that place.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no view on top of it

Comment: You can't set the size of a cell by setting it's frame. The cell is within a container that has a size defined by the tableview delegate method sizeForRowAtIndexPath. Your new 100px are outside those bounds. They're simply visible because the cell's clipsToBounds property is set as NO. You need to trigger a reload of your tableview and return a new size on that method.

Comment: Please give some code